# RxJs - Ajax error 0 instead of 502 occurres

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs

I'm using `RxJS 6` and it's `ajax` module to fetch data. After getting `502` from my API, I expect status of the response object pasted below would be `502`. However the status is `0`.

From all kinds of issues, I understand status `0` is the default status for all response object generated from `RxJS.ajax` and after response is received the status value is overwritten to the one that the server provides.

Here, clearly the server provides status code `502`, but the status in the response object is still `0`.

[image: response]

Have you encountered this behaviour? Is there a fix/workaround?
Or is it legitimate bug in the library, and I should post it to their issue tracker?

Comment: Are you maybe logging the object before Rx had the chance to modify it? You could try to log in the next digest-cycle with ```setTimeout( () => {log}, 0)```

Comment: Even with `setTimouet()` the status code is still `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

When the API falls on 5xx, our server fails to provide appropriate CORS header back to the browser in `OPTIONS` response.

This prevents Javascript from successfully overwrite the response object and error with status `0` is catched.

It should be handled on server side, or client can infer that status `0` should be handled as status `5xx`. (that is however bit hacky, as status `0` normally refers to things like network outage).